# Menuitem select function call issue in Jquery/AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

I want to call the below AJAX Javascript function **(Code-1)** on select and click of the menu item named **"Log Report"**  (Code-2) and populate the results of the test.txt in a html text box in the page .

The below **code-1** can read the text.txt and I want it to be invoked or called when I select the menuitem option named **Log Report**. Can anyone suggest how can I make this work for my below code. How can **I call the code 1 function in the menuitem Log Report and populate the text in it in a textbox**?

**P.S:** Code 2 drop down UI can be viewed by copying the code in test.txt and save as test.html. Open this in a IE or Firefox.

**CODE-1**

```
      <script type="text/javascript">  
function  contentDisp()
{
    $.ajax({
    url : "test.txt",
    success : function (data) {
    $("#contentArea").html(data);
    }
    });
}
 </script>
```

**CODE-2**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test screen</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#menu" ).menu();
});
</script>
<style>
.ui-menu { width: 230px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="menu">
<li>Server</li>
<li>Logs
<ul>
<li>Log Report</li>
</ul>
</li>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way is to give an ID to the "Log Report" li and attach a click event on it, something like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li>Server</li>
<li>Logs
<ul>
<li id="log-report-link">Log Report</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

And in the script tag something like this:

```
<script>
    $( "#menu" ).menu();
    $("#log-report-link").click(function(){
        contentDisp();
    });
</script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: How can I populate the values into a text box. In the above suggestion you said the way I can call the AJAX function but can you suggest me how can I bind or display the results of this .txt file in a text box in html.

Comment: Well I was guessing that #contentArea was a textarea and your "Code-1" should work. Anyway, It would be better to use `$("input-or-textarea-selector").val(data);` instead of using `.html()`